# C regarding functions

Tags: c

I am new to programming and am trying to make a program with 3 functions that ask the user for an input `c` for a circle or `t` for a right-angle triangle. Then entering the radius if `c` or two sides if triangle. I am having trouble with the `display` function, it is printing the answers as `0` on both occasions. If I enter the `printf` statements inside the circle or triangle function it prints properly but I need the function `display`. This is my code. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI 3.14

void circle(int num, double area, double per) {
    area = (double)(M_PI * pow(num, 2));
    per = (double)(2 * M_PI * num);
}

void rt(int num, int num1, double area, double per) {
    area = (double)(0.5 * num * num1);
    per = (double)((num + num1) + sqrt(pow(num, 2) + pow(num1, 2)));
}

void display(char entry, double area, double per) {
    if (entry == 'c') {
        printf("The circle has area %.1lf and perimeter %.1lf.\n", area, per);
    } else {
        printf("The right triangle has area %.1lf and perimeter %.1lf.\n", area, per);

    }
}

int main() {        
    char entry;
    int num;
    int num1;
    double area = 0;
    double per = 0;

    printf("Please enter 'c' for a circle or 't' for a right triangle\n");
    scanf("%c", &entry);
    if (entry == 'c') {
        printf("Please enter the radius for the circle.\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        getchar();
        circle(num, area, per);
    } else
    if (entry == 't') {
        printf("Please enter the length of two sides.\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &num, &num1);
        getchar();
        rt(num, num1, area, per);
    } else {            
        printf("Invalid input!");
    }

    display(entry, area, per);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't redefine `M_PI`, especially as  `3.14` is a pretty bad approximation.

Comment: @chqrlie: If it was `#define`d in `math.h`, OP would get an redefinition-error. `M_PI` is not part of the C standard.

Comment: @Olaf: The OP most likely got a warning, not an error. Posix mandates that `M_PI` be defined in `<math.h>`.  If the OP does not have it, at least define it correctly as `#define M_PI        3.14159265358979323846264338327950288`

Comment: @chqrlie: I don't see where OP does get a diagnostic message for that line. POSIX is not C. There are much more non-POSIX systems out there than POSIX and there is no indicator OP does use a POSIX system. But I agree OP using a different name and a more precise approximation for PI is a good idea.

Comment: I am compiling using a rasberry pi with the  argument  -gcc -Wall -std=c99 filename.c -lm. I did not get an error but I understand now its bad programming thank you guys. I actually tried compiling it with just gcc filename.c -lm and I do indeed get a redefinition warming since it is defined in math.h

Comment: @Olaf: I made a wild guess, I am willing to bet that the OP *most likely got a warning*, in any case, sadly, it would only get a redefinition warning, not an error. An easy to define `PI` is to compute it as `acos(-1.0)`.

Comment: @Olaf: OK, I lose, gcc sucks. It is just so sad to see the committee waste energy normalizing silly inventions like `<iso646.h>` or digraphs and disregard fundamentally useful stuff like `strdup`, math constants, etc. that are consistent sources of bugs and imprecision, almost every day here on SO.

Comment: @chqrlie: Using a function does make the macro not being a constant. I agree about adding a constant for PI (whatever name). I'd also like to see more moving twards a modern C, e.g. `enums` with user-defined types like in C++11, strictly requiring function prototypes (not the old `int f()` syntax), etc. But OP already clarified.

Comment: @chqrlie: What do you mean with "gcc sucks"? Imo it is one of the least sucking compilers. But admittedly, I don't use clang for my embedded projects.

Comment: @Olaf: issuing a redefinition warning by default and not with -std=c99 is counterproductive. -std=c99 should not mean disable posix when you are on a posix system.

Comment: @chqrlie: Hmm, maybe there is another option to enable POSIX? gcc defaults to `gnu11` (versions since 5), resp. `gnu90`, both include extensions, possibly some POSIX option? Note this is likely not gcc, but glibc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `circle` and `rt` functions just update their arguments, not the local variables in `main`.  You must pass pointers to these for `circle` and `rt` to update them.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void circle(int num, double *area, double *per) {
    *area = M_PI * pow(num, 2);
    *per = 2 * M_PI * num;
}

void rt(int num, int num1, double *area, double *per) {
    *area = 0.5 * num * num1;
    *per = (num + num1) + sqrt(pow(num, 2) + pow(num1, 2));
}

void display(char entry, double area, double per) {
    if (entry == 'c') {
        printf("The circle has area %.1lf and perimeter %.1lf.\n", area, per);
    } else {
        printf("The right triangle has area %.1lf and perimeter %.1lf.\n", area, per);

    }
}

int main() {        
    char entry;
    int num, num1;
    double area = 0;
    double per = 0;

    printf("Please enter 'c' for a circle or 't' for a right triangle\n");
    scanf("%c", &entry);
    if (entry == 'c') {
        printf("Please enter the radius for the circle.\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        getchar();
        circle(num, &area, &per);
    } else
    if (entry == 't') {
        printf("Please enter the length of two sides.\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &num, &num1);
        getchar();
        rt(num, num1, &area, &per);
    } else {          
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
    }
    display(entry, area, per);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's correct. Review how C passes parameters for different purposes.

Comment: @johnelemans: What do you mean with "for different ..."? C is strictily pass by value - no exceptions.

Comment: @Olaf: functions are passed by reference, arrays decay as pointers, which is a form of passing by reference.

Comment: @chqrlie: Functions are passed by pointer, which is a value. Same for arrays. Both are true pointers, not references. You have to dereference it first to get the object (implicit conversion like for the postfix operators `()` resp. `[]` does not change the fact). A reference is a name which has no value on its own (see C++'s references or Python). C does not support references, you can always get the value of these pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your help chqrlie, I need to learn properly what pointers are used for.